# ADB connection error:Unable to obtain debug bridge in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

After updating Android Studio I don't able to open the "Android Device Monitor".I am getting this error "ADB connection error:Unable to obtain debug bridge" and Android Device Monitor does not open.Please check the attached image.I run the Android Studio into mac not windows.Please help to me how i can solve this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

go to windows task manager -->processes. Click "end process" ,after selecting adb.exe in the list. After this restart the android studio and run adb. now it will run. This is what i had done in my windows which gave me the solution for this problem.